# Set Env Var and Access From Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

This is probably a really stupid question, but how do I set an Environment Variable in Bash, then access it in a shell script?

```
kkeiper@machine:/home/kkeiper $ export APIKEY="adsf"
```

In bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $APIKEY; # prints a blank line
echo $(env | grep APIKEY); # wouldn't return APIKEY even if it did work, but this also prints a blank string
```

Comment: Your example works for me on GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0).  Either `$ export APIKEY="asdf"; ./foo.sh` or `env APIKEY=asdf ./foo.sh` outputs `asdf` followed by `APIKEY=asdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show should work!  It does for me:

```
$ export APIKEY="asfw"
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $APIKEY
env | grep APIKEY
$ bash -x script.sh
+ echo asfw
asfw
+ env
+ grep APIKEY
APIKEY=asfw
$ sudo bash script.sh
Password:

$
```

Note that you don't need the semicolons or the `echo $(...)` notation in the script — but they don't do any damage either.

(Tested Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, Bash 3.2.51.  However, I don't expect it to matter. Only true Bourne shells don't support the `export VAR=value` notation — and you'll have to look hard to find a shell with that limitation these days; Solaris `/bin/sh`, perhaps.)

*Example with `sudo` added after question in comments. Yes, `sudo` unsets stray environment variables such as `APIKEY`.*

More notes on `sudo`:

```
$ env | wc -l
      24
$ env | grep APIKEY
APIKEY=asfw
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $APIKEY
env | grep APIKEY
env | wc -l
$ bash script.sh
asfw
APIKEY=asfw
      23
$ sudo bash script.sh

      18
$
```

One day, I'll investigate the what and the why for the difference between 24 and 23 environment variables without `sudo` being involved, but clearly `sudo` eliminated a number of variables (5 or 6, including APIKEY specifically).

> How to ensure that environment variables are preserved?

If you know which ones need to be preserved, then:

1. The `sudo` man page says:

   > `-E` The `-E` (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset option
   >                  in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when either the matching command
   >                  has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudoers(5).
2. You can arrange to relay the environment variables to the commands environment:

   ```
   $ sudo -E bash script.sh
   Password:
   asfw
   APIKEY=asfw
         26
   $ sudo bash -c "APIKEY='$APIKEY' bash script.sh"
   asfw
   APIKEY=asfw
   SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash -c APIKEY='asfw' bash script.sh
         19
   $
   ```

   The appearance of `SUDO_COMMAND` in the environment is interesting.

   (Note that the `bash script.sh` notation is only needed because I've not made `script.sh` executable. If it was executable, I could type either `script.sh` or `./script.sh` depending on whether it is in a directory on my `$PATH` or not.)

Comment: would it not work if I'm running the script as sudo?

Comment: I'm writing a script to create an Apache vhost that then uses an API to add a new A record for the new test site, so I need to run as sudo.

Comment: Ah, mebbe, mebbe not...thinks — does `sudo` reset the environment? Yes, it does.

Comment: AHHHHH. That would be it then, because as soon as I disable the "root-check", then the script prints the right key

Comment: For whatever it's worth, could you add how to preserve env variables to your answer? `sudo -E ./mkhost-staging.sh kkeiper` works for me